# Issue using a data model from a static library

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, static-libraries

I am developing an iOS application that uses a static library I have also created.

I have a data model in the library I would like to use in the iOS application.

The normal Apple supplied NSManagedObjectModel getter looks like this:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
{
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Honeycomb" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

I have modified the getter to look in my static library resource bundle to get the data model:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *honeycombBundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"HoneycombResources" withExtension:@"bundle"];
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle bundleWithURL:honeycombBundleURL] URLForResource:@"Honeycomb" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

I get the URL for the model returning correctly, however when I go to look at the location the URL is pointing to, the only file there is "Versioninfo.plist" - there's no actual .mom file!

I have set up my resource bundle for the static library as laid out in this article http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

All of the other resources (.nib and .png) are showing up properly in the bundle when I browse to it in the file system, I am just missing the .mom file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

For some reason Xcode had "imported" the .xcdatamodel file, but the source file was not actually in the project directory.  I copied the file to where Xcode thought it was, and it all worked.